# NextJS: Axios is returning 401 error for authenticated pages where JWT tokens are set as HttpOnly cookie after login from django

Tags: reactjs, django, cookies, next.js, cookie-httponly

I have set the access and refresh tokens as HttpOnly cookie from Django backend. In NextJS frontend, the login view works and it shows the HttpOnly cookies are present in the **XHR** tab. Therefore, it must work for any other authenticated views also. But when I make the request from any other pages with `Axios` it returns:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 401
```

As far as I understand, the Django server attaches the httponly cookies to very requests. Therefore, my request to the server must have the cookies in it but the cookies are empty!

It works with Postman very well but not in the browser.

My NextJS page:

```
export default function profilePage() {
    return (
        <div className={styles.maincontainer}>
            <p>Hi</p>
        </div>
    );};

export async function getServerSideProps() {
    const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/profile/';
    const headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
    const resp = await axios.get(url, Headers=headers)
    const data = resp.json;
    console.log(data)
    return {}
};
```

In my login page, the cookies are present in **XHR** tab:
[image: xhr tab]

But still if I send request from any authenticated page, it is showing error 401! What is wrong?

Comment: Just to make sure, are you using Next.js API routes for the request? Or is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/profile` your Django server?

Comment: Yes it is Django server.

Comment: An axios request in getServerSideProps is not made from the browser.  It is made from your NextJS Node backend.  That request won't have cookies on it from the browser automagically.  You'll have to read them from the browser request and copy them to the axios request.

Comment: How do I do that? I tried with `const cookies = ctx.req.header.cookie`, still it's the same 401 error, does it not work with HttpOnly cookies?

Comment: @forest where you able to resolve this? If so, how?