# How do I use proxy in Nextjs to send HttpOnly cookie to django on different domain?

Tags: django, proxy, next.js, cross-domain, cookie-httponly

I previously posted about not being able to send HttpOnly cookie from nextJS to django either from getServerSideProps or from useEffect [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66587351/nextjs-axios-is-returning-401-error-for-authenticated-pages-where-jwt-tokens-ar). I think the reason is that my django and Nextjs are running on different domains. So I need to have same domains for both back-end and front-end. Does it mean that requests from nextJS should go from 127.0.0.1:8000 instead of 127.0.0.1:3000?

If yes, do I need to use proxy within Nextjs?

Also, I have set-up django-cors-headers, does it still require proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You'll need to set up a proxy server that will forward your requests from 127.0.0.1:3000 to 127.0.0.1:8000. That way, your cookies will be shared with your backend server since the browser will assume they are from the same origin.

As for setting up a http proxy on nextjs, you can refer to this [Github Answer](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/14057)

Setting django CORS headers will not apply to your cookies. CORS refers to requests from different origins and setting these headers will allow your backend to receive requests from different origins as you have specified in your `allowedHosts` declerative. Cookies can be shared within different subdomains but never different domains.